# How to make prediction with custom-trained keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am a totally newcomer to TensorFlow. I have followed some of the tutorials and worked out my first multi-class classification model.

I am not sure my layers are reasonably designed, anyway, the accuracy in the test is 0.98 or so.

The thing is I cannot use my model to predict a new input. Here is my code and the data I used to train the model.

The data has 10 columns, the last one is the class names. The model is to use a row of 9 values to predict which class is the row fits in.

All the codes were run in colab.

```
!pip install sklearn
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import feature_column
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

index_col = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'r']
dataframe = pd.read_csv('drive/MyDrive/Book2.csv', names=index_col)

train, test = train_test_split(dataframe, test_size=0.2)
train, val = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.2)

train_labels = train.filter('r')
train = train.drop('r', axis=1)

test_labels = test.filter('r')
test = test.drop('r', axis=1)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train, train_labels, epochs=20)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test,  test_labels, verbose=2)

result = model.predict(pd.DataFrame([1, 3, 0, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2]))
```

Here is the console error I got.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-942b3f127f67> in <module>()
----> 1 result = model.predict([1, 3, 0, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2])

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    984           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    985             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 986               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    987             else:
    988               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1569 predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1559 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1285 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2833 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3608 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1552 run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1525 predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1013 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:255 assert_input_compatibility
        ' but received input with shape ' + display_shape(x.shape))

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_2 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 9 but received input with shape (None, 1)
```

Book2.csv is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W-LZk6PtsGYF1peLZYCFThYULhaF7kfT/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Maybe try an ```np.array``` rather than a ```pd.DataFrame``` as your prediction input.

Comment: Your link to dataset is private. What is `train.shape`?

Comment: Sorry, @Kaveh, Link updated. train.shape is (7133, 10).

Comment: @JackGee, the result is same. I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataframe passed to `predict` has shape `(9,1)`. It's shape should be like the shape of train dataset (except first dimension) you have passed.

Simply transpose your data to change shape from `(9,1)` to `(1,9)`:

```
result = model.predict(pd.DataFrame([1, 3, 0, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2]).T)
```

P.S: `(9,1)` means 9 samples, each of which with 1 feature which is incompatible with your model expectation. But `(1,9)` means 1 sample with 9 features.

Comment: Thank you. Is this keras model or SavedModel? The final purpose is to deploy this model in front end and make predictions with tensorflow.js. I think this is keras model, right?

Comment: This is just a model. If you save it like `model.save('model.h5')` it is keras model (1 file will be saved). If you save it like `model.save("path/to/folder/")` it is SavedModel (several files and folders will be created).

Comment: And, what about in tensorflow.js? Can I do like this? result = model.predict([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);?

Comment: What do you want to do? Just inference via tfjs? Or also creating and training model with  tfjs?

Comment: Just inference. I use only model. That means the whole js starts with const model = loadGraphModel(...); No training.

Comment: So, you first should convert your model to supported format with tfjs. then load it in js and getting inference like this: `const input = tf.tensor2d([array_with_shape_1x9]);` then `const result = model.predict(input);`. If you want details of code, You may ask another question in order to I share some codes with you.

Comment: A new question posted. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68666584/12992521 Hope you can help me again. Thanks @Kaveh

Comment: Can we write our own custom `model.predict` function in Keras please?