# How to use saved model in tensorflow.js

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I have found that I could use python-trained `tensorflow` model in tensorflow.js.

I converted the model with `tensorflowjs_wizard` and followed their instructions.

As a result, I got `json` file and `bin` file(this is the model file for js usage).

But when I tried to use the model, I got stuck with some logical hits. I used `pandas` dataframe to train model and made some tests and predictions with `pandas`, but how to do it in js? I did it myself but got some errors.

To make it short, I have these questions.

1. How to use `model.predict()` in js? Is it possible to use it like this?

   ```
   result = model.predict([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);
   ```
2. What is .bin file doing here? Will it be OK to delete this?
3. I found that `loadLayerModel()` or `loadGraphModel()` is used to load model from file, what is used when?

Here are the HTML and js files(as in tensorflow.js tutorials).

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>TensorFlow</title>
  <!-- Import TensorFlow.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
  
  <!-- Import the main script file -->
  <script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
async function getData() {
  const a = tf.tensor2d([1, 3, 0, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2]);
  return a;
}

async function run() {
  const model = await tf.loadGraphModel('/json/model.json');
  const tensor = getData();
  const result = model.predict(tensor);
  console.log(result);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run)
```

This is the console error message.

```
tensor_ops.js:209 Uncaught (in promise) Error: tensor2d() requires shape to be provided when `values` are a flat/TypedArray
    at Object.uy [as tensor2d] (tensor_ops.js:209)
    at getData (script.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.run (script.js:9)

graph_executor.js:119 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot compute the outputs [Identity] from the provided inputs []. Missing the following inputs: [dense_21_input]
    at t.e.compile (graph_executor.js:119)
    at t.e.execute (graph_executor.js:152)
    at t.e.execute (graph_model.js:288)
    at t.e.predict (graph_model.js:242)
    at HTMLDocument.run (script.js:10)
```

Folder tree:

```
index.html

script.js

json/model.json

json/group1-shard1of1.bin
```

Comment: You have everything ready to go bro. Just care about shape as I said in earlier post. Your shapes should be (N,9). Which N is number of samples you want to predict. If you want to predict 1 sample at a time, N is 1. So, make your array like this: `const a = tf.tensor2d([1, 3, 0, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2],[1,9]);`  `.json` file stores your model architecture, and `.bin` file(s) stores trained weights of your model. You can not delete it.

Comment: Still showing this error. graph_executor.js:119 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot compute the outputs [Identity] from the provided inputs []. Missing the following inputs: [dense_6_input]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to complete @Nikita's answer:

1. Since your training data was all int, the model expects int numbers. It's better to convert them to float while training. For example like this:

```
train = np.array(train).astype('float32')
train_labels = np.array(train_labels).astype('float32')
model.fit(train ,train_labels , epochs=20)
```

2. One other thing may be important is that, since you have not defined activation function for your last layer, you get prediction in any range, even negative numbers. It's better to remove `from_logits=True` from loss function and add `activation=softmax` to last layer:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4,activation="softmax")
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics=['accuracy'])
```

3. You will get 4 numbers as output, and if you want to get category index, you may use `argmax` after prediction. So, modification code maybe something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"> </script>   
<script>
    async function run(){
        const MODEL_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8887/model.json';
        const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(MODEL_URL);
        console.log(model.summary());
        const input = tf.tensor2d([1, 3, 0, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2], [1,9]);
        const result = await model.predict(input);
        const res = await result.argMax(axis=1);
        alert(res)
    }
    run();
</script>
</head> 
<body></body>   
</html>
```

4. `.json` file stores your model architecture, and `.bin` file(s) stores trained weights of your model. You can not delete it.
5. `tf.loadLayersModel()` loads a model composed of layer objects, including its topology and optionally weights. It's limitations is ,this is not applicable to TensorFlow `SavedModel`s or their converted forms. For those models, you should use `tf.loadGraphModel()`.

Comment: thanks again. Why float is better than int? Maybe being not separate?

Comment: I didn't mean it is better in performance (I don't know if it has any effect on performance). But if you set data to float, then your layers will be constructed in tfjs to expect float. You can convert int to float without loosing information. But if you convert float to int, you may loose some information (if you have some input between int numbers). Note that neural networks work with float numbers (probability) in nature. It means all your inputs finally will be converted to float. And also this restriction to set dtype maybe removed in future releases, then you don't have such challenge.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of networking, I found that these two are the reasons.

```
const a = tf.tensor2d([1, 3, 0, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2],[1,9],'int32');
```

and

```
const tensor = await getData();
```

The former reshapes the input data. The latter is important, to wait for data to be read.